# AWS Instance get removed from SSM Managed instances after SSM Agent update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm able to launch an instance and have it become managed by **Systems Manager**. That is, until it automatically updates the SSM Agent. The update is successful, updating from `3.0.161.0` to `3.0.854.0`. The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

I can still connect to the instance using the Session Manager despite it not appearing in the Managed Instances list.

Not sure if this is relevant, but here is the `/var/log/amazon/ssm/errors.log`:

```
2021-03-21 03:56:50 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessagingDeliveryService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:50 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [OfflineService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:51 ERROR [Process @ backend.go.139] [ssm-document-worker] [28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b] [DataBackend] failed to unmarshal plugin config: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type string
2021-03-21 03:56:51 ERROR [Messaging @ messaging.go.145] [ssm-document-worker] [28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b] messaging pipeline process datagram encountered error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditionsof type string
2021-03-21 03:56:50 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessageGatewayService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:50 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessagingDeliveryService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:50 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [OfflineService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:50 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessageGatewayService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:51 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessagingDeliveryService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:51 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [OfflineService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
2021-03-21 03:56:51 ERROR [GetDocumentState @ docmanager.go.147] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessageGatewayService] encountered error with message json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Configuration.InstancePluginsInformation.Configuration.Preconditions of type contracts.PreconditionArgument while reading Interim state of command from file - 28785d7e-bfaf-414b-bd02-fc3a1746610b
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Did you use `AWS-UpdateSSMAgent` to update it?

Comment: Yes. Well not me manually.It was done autonatically right after the instance launched but I can see that it was executed in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a bug from AWS. I use Terraform and with the exact same configs as I had tested yesterday it now works as expected.